# Interactive choropleth map with Leaflet and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to modify this [repo](https://github.com/cat-lord/crime_analysis/tree/master/shinyapps/basic_choropleth_map) to display a choropleth map and use a sliderInput to update the map. Everything Ok until I try to animate the slider input, nothing happens . I get this console error: input_binding_slider.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined.

This is the code i'm using:

```
library(dplyr) ; library(rgdal) ; library(leaflet)

gdp = read.csv("mexico2.csv", header= T) %>%
  as.data.frame()

mexico <- readOGR("mexico.shp", layer = "mexico", encoding = "UTF-8")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(7, offset = 1,
           br(),
           div(h4(textOutput("title"), align = "center"), style = "color:black"),
           div(h5(textOutput("period"), align = "center"), style = "color:black"),
           br())),
  fluidRow(
    column(7, offset = 1,
           leafletOutput("map", height="530"),
           br(),
           actionButton("reset_button", "Reset view")),
    column(3,
           uiOutput("category", align = "left")))
))

server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  output$category <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("category", "Year:",
                 min=1994, max = 1999,
                 value = 1994, sep = "", animate=TRUE)
  })  

  selected <- reactive({
    subset(gdp,
           category==input$category)
  })

  output$title <- renderText({
    req(input$category)
    paste0(input$category, " GDP by State")
  })

  output$period <- renderText({
    req(input$category)
    paste("...")
  })

  lat <- 23
  lng <- -102
  zoom <- 5

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
      setView(lat = lat, lng = lng, zoom = zoom)
  })

  observe({
    mexico@data <- left_join(mexico@data, selected())

    qpal <- colorQuantile("YlGn", mexico$value, n = 5, na.color = "#bdbdbd")

    popup <- paste0("<strong>ID: </strong>",
                    mexico$id,
                    "<br><strong>Estado: </strong>",
                    mexico$name,
                    "<br><strong>Valor: </strong>",
                    mexico$value)

    leafletProxy("map", data = mexico) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
      clearShapes() %>% 
      clearControls() %>% 
      addPolygons(data = mexico, fillColor = ~qpal(value), fillOpacity = 0.7, 
                  color = "white", weight = 2, popup = popup) %>%
      addLegend(pal = qpal, values = ~value, opacity = 0.7,
                position = 'bottomright', 
                title = paste0(input$category, "<br>"))
  })

  observe({
    input$reset_button
    leafletProxy("map") %>% setView(lat = lat, lng = lng, zoom = zoom)
  })      

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is a link to the [shinyapp](https://neek05.shinyapps.io/gdp1/)

Any help would be aprecieted. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a naming mistake. You named your `htmlOutput` **and** your `sliderOutput` for "category". Internally, this messes things up.

Just change e.g. the output into

```
uiOutput("categoryOutput", align = "left")
```

and

```
output$categoryOutput <- renderUI({ ... })
```

and you should be good to go.

**Edit: Full Code**

```
library(dplyr) ; library(rgdal) ; library(leaflet)

gdp = read.csv("mexico2.csv", header= T) %>%
  as.data.frame()

mexico <- readOGR("mexico.shp", layer = "mexico", encoding = "UTF-8")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(7, offset = 1,
           br(),
           div(h4(textOutput("title"), align = "center"), style = "color:black"),
           div(h5(textOutput("period"), align = "center"), style = "color:black"),
           br())),
  fluidRow(
    column(7, offset = 1,
           leafletOutput("map", height="530"),
           br(),
           actionButton("reset_button", "Reset view")),
    column(3,
           uiOutput("categoryOut", align = "left")))
))

server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  output$categoryOut <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("category", "Year:",
                 min=1994, max = 1999,
                 value = 1994, sep = "", animate=TRUE)
  })  

  selected <- reactive({
    subset(gdp,
           category==input$category)
  })

  output$title <- renderText({
    req(input$category)
    paste0(input$category, " GDP by State")
  })

  output$period <- renderText({
    req(input$category)
    paste("...")
  })

  lat <- 23
  lng <- -102
  zoom <- 5

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
      setView(lat = lat, lng = lng, zoom = zoom)
  })

  observe({
    mexico@data <- left_join(mexico@data, selected())

    qpal <- colorQuantile("YlGn", mexico$value, n = 5, na.color = "#bdbdbd")

    popup <- paste0("<strong>ID: </strong>",
                    mexico$id,
                    "<br><strong>Estado: </strong>",
                    mexico$name,
                    "<br><strong>Valor: </strong>",
                    mexico$value)

    leafletProxy("map", data = mexico) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
      clearShapes() %>% 
      clearControls() %>% 
      addPolygons(data = mexico, fillColor = ~qpal(value), fillOpacity = 0.7, 
                  color = "white", weight = 2, popup = popup) %>%
      addLegend(pal = qpal, values = ~value, opacity = 0.7,
                position = 'bottomright', 
                title = paste0(input$category, "<br>"))
  })

  observe({
    input$reset_button
    leafletProxy("map") %>% setView(lat = lat, lng = lng, zoom = zoom)
  })      

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but that didn't work. Actually, after my post I changed the name to "yearOutput" because I thought it was more descriptive. But the problem with the slider still remains.

Comment: Okay, I was wondering, because I got the `Error: Type of h is undefined`, so not what you got...

Comment: @neek05 Well, no. I just got onto your shinyserver website and did nothing but change the id of the div that contains the slider. And voilà, the animation worked without error messages. Look at this screenshot: http://imgur.com/oIyprzn

Comment: It's weird. I uploaded a new shiny app:(https://neek05.shinyapps.io/leaflet/) with the name changed and still not working. It works only if I change the id of the div inside the browser to another name (including the previous one: "category"). Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: @neek05 No!, maybe I wasn't clear enough the first time. It doesn't matter what the name is, as long as the `sliderInput`-ID **differs** from the `uiOutput`-ID. You always name them the same. Check the full Code in my edited answer.